# publishing and discovering REST web services

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, amazon-web-services, uddi

I am a student and new to web services. I have an academic project where I have to do dynamic service composition, where the client(coded client, not the human client) will search for web services and out of the searched web services it will choose any one to call at run time. I tried to implement it using SOAP based web services(JAX-WS). But I found on the internet that SOAP based services are not much in use so I tried to implement in on REST.

Now my problem is where I should publish the REST service. With SOAP(JAX-WS) services there was an entity UDDI where the service could be published and searched.

Kindly help me out with following issues:

1. Could we publish and discover REST web services without using UDDI(because UDDI is tough to implement).
2. If there is no way other than UDDI, then how could I publish a REST service to UDDI.
3. For the given scenario did I made a right choice by choosing REST as the implementation mode or should I shift back to SOAP(JAX-WS).

I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383702/is-there-an-uddi-or-any-other-registry-for-restful-webservices

Comment: @ioseb thanks for you post. After reading the link I got some idea about how to search a REST service using URL. I have one more query, suppose I want to call any specific method of my web service like 'myMethod(String s)' then how could we do that. In case of SOAP services we were able to directly call the method like 'proxyObject.myMethod("string")' using the proxy object present at client. Since there is not proxy present in REST and the methods provided are GET, PUT, DELETE etc. so how could one call any other method that is specific to service class.

Answer (score 0):

Given your needs, would [apigee](http://www.apigee.com) cut it?

(Just curious)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that UDDI is compatible to REST services  :[http://apachejuddi.blogspot.fr/2014/01/uddi-as-registry-for-rest-services.html](http://It%20seems%20that%20now%20UDDI%20is%20complaitente%20to%20REST%20%20:http://apachejuddi.blogspot.fr/2014/01/uddi-as-registry-for-rest-services.html)